# Exception object in the catch block

Tags: c#

Is it possible to get an Exception object in the `catch` block without an argument, as shown below, and if so, how?

```
try
{

  // code possibly throwing an exception to be caught below

} catch
{

  // Note the catch here has no argument, in contrast to catch(Exception ex).
  // If possible, I want to get an Exception object without the argument (Exception ex). 

}
```

Comment: No. What are you trying to accomplish? Why can't you use the normal syntax?

Comment: @user5525674 Writing `catch { }` means you *explicitly* don't care about the exception object. If you *do* care about the exception object, you ***must*** write `catch (Exception ex) { }`. There's no two ways about it.

Comment: I can use the normal syntax, no problem. Sometimes we think and deviate from what the normal syntax provides. For what it's worth here is what I want to do.



I don't need (Exception ex) in release mode but only in debug. If I can get an Exception object, all I need to do is comment out the lines in release mode (I have a faster method for this). If I have to use (Exception ex) I have to remove part of a code line.

There is nothing unusual doing it differently. I am just looking for possibilities. If it cannot be done, that's fine, but it is not a sin not to stick to the 'normal syntax'.

Comment: @user5525674 If you had put that in the original question it may not have been closed, but seeing how it was, I can't add this as an answer. If you want to do what you are asking, this is very simple using precompilation symbols, I put an example [on pastebin](http://pastebin.com/6fiJVx8S) showing how to do what you are asking. It does not require you to comment out code when changing from debug to release.

Comment: I have this already but thank you for the trouble. Now I now what I wasn't sure about Exception object. Call it curiosity, I had this nagging thought that there may be some class that exposes the current Exception object. I now know this is not the case. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only thing you can do in this instance is to write `throw;` within that `catch` block.

That will rethrow the caught exception, which something higher up the call stack could catch and interpret.

In not writing `catch (Exception ex)` you've specifically told the runtime that you're not interested in the exception specifics at that point.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no, it's not possible. Why would you even want to do that, though? You should catch the specific types of exceptions your try block can throw and handle them accordingly. If you have just 1 catch-all that doesn't care about the specific type of exception, then just use `(Exception ex)` like you said.